# python3.6.6にてcv2エラーが発生します

Tags: python, opencv

pythonについて独学している者です。
この度python 3.6.6を使用中に調べても類例や解決法がわからないエラーが発生したので知恵をお借りしたいです。

エラー箇所

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQEAmain.py", line 157, in <module>
    img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

環境
Windows10
Python 3.6.6

以下エラー部分のコードです。

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ファイルを開く
    f = open(FLAGS.train, 'r')
    # データを入れる配列
    train_image = []
    train_label = []
    for line in f:
        # 改行を除いてスペース区切りにする
        line = line.rstrip()
        l = line.split()
        # データを読み込んで28x28に縮小
        img = cv2.imread(l[0])
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
        # 一列にした後、0-1のfloat値にする
        train_image.append(img.flatten().astype(np.float32)/255.0)
        # ラベルを1-of-k方式で用意する
        tmp = np.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
        tmp[int(l[1])] = 1
        train_label.append(tmp)
    # numpy形式に変換
    train_image = np.asarray(train_image)
    train_label = np.asarray(train_label)
    f.close()
```

初心者なもので恐縮ですが詳しいご解答を頂けると幸いです。

追記

```
./data/train/cats/cat0.jpg
(500, 357, 3)

中略

./data/train/dogs/dog22.jpg
(794, 1000, 3)
./data/train/dogs/dog23.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 174, in <module>
    print(img.shape)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

※こちらの質問は解決しました。
Yasuhiroさんの仰る通り、画像の拡張子の問題でした。
ご協力に感謝致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージ`error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'`から判断すると、画像`img`を読み込むのに失敗していると思われます。

それを確認するために、以下のように`print`文を追加して変数の値がどうなっているか出力してみてください。

```
import os

中略

if __name__ == '__main__':
# カレントディレクトリを取得
print(os.getcwd())
f = open(FLAGS.train, 'r')
train_image = []
train_label = []

for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    l = line.split()
    # l[0]の確認
    print(l[0])
    img = cv2.imread(l[0])
    # imgのサイズの確認
    print(img.shape)

    以下略
```

今回は画像`dog23`が他の画像と同じ`jpg`ではなく`png`だったためそれが読み込まれていなかったためです。`FLAGS.train`の該当部分を`jpg`から`png`に修正すると動作すると思います。

今回のようなエラーは、デバッガーを使うか、printで関係する変数を出力して調べないとわからないです。

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。画像を置く場所が間違っているという事でしょうか？

Comment: 頂いた情報を参考に画像のディレクトリなどを見直してやりなおしてみましたが、同じエラーがでます。

>cv2.imread(l[0])のl[0]が、正しい画像ファイルの位置になっているかを確認して修正するといいと思われます。
この部分についてお教え頂けますか…

Comment: 現在の質問の内容だけでは状況がわからないので、回答に3つのprint文を追加しました。その値がどうなるか教えていただけますか。

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございます。結果を質問部分に追記しました。cat0は試験用に使用している画像の名前です

Comment: `img.shape()`でなくて、`img.shape`でした。他も修正したのでもう一度結果を追記していただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 再び追記しました。
見たところ、用意してある"dog23"の画像がjpgでなくpngでした。この食い違いが原因でしょうか？

Comment: エラーの原因はそれですね。エラーが出る時はこうやって一つ一つ調べて行くしかないのです。